# Get Item from QStandardItemModel for QTableView

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qt-signals, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I have a `QTreeView` in which each node represents a data object. I managed to pack a pointer to this data objects into a `QVariant` so that I know which is selected in the Tree. I can access the nodes by the `currentIndex()` function.

The root of the Tree is at `QStandardItemModel::invisibleRootItem()`. Other nodes are added by the parent nodes `appendRow` function. So the Items have no `row` and `column` that I can use in `QStandardItemModel::item()`.

Is there a way to give the nodes valid coordinates or to retrieve the items without coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

In QStandardItemModel, there is a [item(int row, int column = 0)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#item) method. Qt nomenclature doesn't use 'get' as prefix of getters methods.

Comment: Thanks. I was always looking in QAbstractItemModel. But I can't use row and column as in a tree they are relative to the parent node.

Comment: Nope, item() always returns 0.
`for (int i = -100; i < 100; i++)
    for (int j = -100; j < 100; j++)
        if (static_cast<QStandardItemModel>(m_ui->treeView->model()).item(i, j) != 0)
            qDebug() << i << j << static_cast<QStandardItemModel>(m_ui->treeView->model()).item(i, j);`
--> No output.

Comment: Thanks ! that was the thing I need it so much :)

Comment: One of the best examples of SO non-answers. How does this answer the question if OP stated that `row` and `column` are useless if `QStandardItemModel` models a tree? (Maybe this part was added to the question after the answer, but still...so frustrating)

Comment: You're right, but as you may have noticed, the original question was drastically different. Before taking time to post a disrespectful comment, maybe you could take a few more time to check the history of this SO post ? The original question was "Why is there no getItem() method in QStandardItemModel?". This answer seems perfectly valid. But OP reworded his question later, and the answer is now pointless. Continue to search a solution to your problem, but please avoid this kind of behavior on SO. Thanks